# How to play sound on click edittext

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design

I want to play sound on onclick eddittext. But I am facing problem to play sound on single click edittext. It is working from second click onward. And I don't want to remove focus from edittext. Please help me.

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/res3"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

 <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/input_layout_mail"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

 <EditText
     android:id="@+id/mail"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:singleLine="true"
     android:textSize="20sp"
     android:maxLength="50"
     android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
     android:hint="@string/mailid" />
 </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
```

Here is my Java code

```
emailid.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
         @Override
         public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
             playSound("click.mp3");
             return false;
         }
     });
public void playSound(final String p_fileName)
     {
    try
     {

        if (m_player != null && m_player.isPlaying())
        {
            m_player.stop();
            m_player.release();
            m_player = null;
        }
        else
        {
            m_player.release();
        }

        m_player = new MediaPlayer();
        m_player.reset();
        AssetFileDescriptor m_descriptor = getAssets().openFd(p_fileName);
        m_player.setDataSource(m_descriptor.getFileDescriptor(), m_descriptor.getStartOffset(), m_descriptor.getLength());
        m_descriptor.close();

        m_player.prepare();
        m_player.setVolume(1f, 1f);
        m_player.setLooping(false);

            m_player.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {

            }
        });
        m_player.start();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: use android:focusable="false" in edittext

Comment: If I removing focus then android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout effect not working. So,I don't want to remove focus from edittext.

Comment: I also tried using onTouchListener but no use

Comment: can you post your onTouch event code

Comment: did you tried `setOnFocusChangeListener` ?

Comment: @H Raval...Plz check I have added the java code

Comment: Above code is working, but not on the single click.

Comment: after much consideration, I found that,,,,,,,,,,The first click event focuses the control, while the second click event actually fires the OnClickListener

Answer (score 1):

You can use OnFocusChangeListener for handle click on EditeText:

```
 emailid.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {          

    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (hasFocus) {
            playSound("click.mp3");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I have tried using OnFocusChangeListener but still not worked.

Answer (score 0):

Is `TextInputLayout` consuming the first click? Try putting the listener on both the `TextInputLayout` and the `EditText`. Personally I would also use an `OnClickListener` instead of an `OnTouchListener` too.

Comment: Can you provide additional detail on why you recommend using the OnClickListener above rather than an OnTouchListener.

Comment: @AJW The question specified onClick so it makes sense to use it instead of onTouch. If you're using onTouch its going to trigger for all sorts of touch events, check out the doc for a full list (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent)
So if all you need is a simple onClick its just simpler to use it instead.

Comment: Understood, I appreciate the follow-up.  Cheers.